# Landlord wants etransfer and claims he did not receive cheque in the mail

Tags: canada, bank-account

I want to stop a rent cheque that i mailed to my landlord 13 days ago and he claims he did not receive it and that I must send him an etransfer immediately now? How long does the process take when I request a stop payment from my bank to the cheque so I can issue an etransfer to the landlord in Toronto as I do not want him to get an etransfer and also deposit the cheque as unsure if he is telling the truth?

Comment: Did you try asking your bank?

Comment: **Are you sure it is your landlord** requesting the e-transfer, and not a criminal posing as him?  [If the request came by e-mail, consider it suspect](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/10/19/scammers-are-conning-home-buyers-out-of-their-down-payment.html) (sender address is easily forged).  If you spoke to him in person about it, not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is called a "stop payment" and is a standard bank service, but different banks implement it slightly differently. Some banks, for example RBC, may allow the payment to go through but reverse it the following day, whereas other banks will prevent the payment from posting to begin with. Banks will generally require that you specify the details such as payment amount, check number, date written, etc. Some banks may charge a fee, but that may be waived if suspected fraud is a factor.

To put a stop payment order in you should start by calling your bank, making sure you have all the payment details ready.